# How can you delete a file as a different user in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I am looking to delete a bunch of folders and files that I think was created under a different account with admin privalages.  **I don't want to log out of my current user and re-login under that admin account.**

How can I delete those folders & files as a different user?

IE: Is there a command via the command line that I can specify a different user account & password to delete those files recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the runas command from command prompt or a run screen:

type windows key-r (to open run window)
runas /user:UserNameHere Explorer .

or

type windows key - r (to open run window)
runas /user:UserNameHere cmd

or

open a command prompt
runas /user:UserNameHere del